# LinkText not working when you have a link with text-transform set to uppercase

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project using Selenium, and found that when I used the Selenium IDE to create a test case, then convert it to WebDriver, when I attempt to run the test using NUnit it does not work as expected.

What I have found is that on the page I'm testing, I have a link which shows in all capital letters (i.e. HOME) this is due to the CSS on the page is `text-transform : uppercase`, when I look at the elements I see that it written as follows (Home).

When I run the test I'm getting

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"link text","selector":"Home"}

The workaround for us is to just ensure that we have our link text to be capital letters. However I was wondering if anyone had seen this before and what they did to combat this?

Comment: I see you have added your thoughts to the issue - in which case please accept my answer - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug/issue within Selenium:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6950

I would vote for the issue, and then think about other ways to locate the element if this is a large blocker for you. XPath will be able to do text-based searching or give the element some classes or an ID that you can use to hook onto.

`By.LinkText` is not the only way to find a link.